# sending special characters like ® via Twilio SMS

Tags: sms, twilio

I'm using Twilio to send SMS messages, and I'd like to include the registration symbol ® in my message. Does anyone know what magic invocation one needs to send it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> **Note:** Twilio now supports Unicode. Per [their documentation](https://www.twilio.com/docs/glossary/what-is-unicode), "By default, SMS messages sent with Twilio support Unicode via UCS-2 character encoding to accurately represent global languages as they’re sent between different geographic locations and across carriers."

The registered trademark [symbol](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Registered_trademark_symbol) ® has no equivalent ASCII representation and according to this [answer](http://forum.twilio.com/twilio/topics/does_twilio_support_sending_unicode_sms_messages) and more recently this [one](http://forum.twilio.com/twilio/topics/what_is_the_twilio_roadmap_for_adding_unicode_and_bulk_sending_support), Twilio doesn't yet support Unicode.

Comment: both links throw 404.